# htaccess hide .php in url partially works

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following working:

```
removes the www section from the url if used
hides the .php section from the url
hides the /parts folder eg:(happylocation.it/parts/anotherpart/this.php into happylocation.it/anotherpart/this.php)
```

Facts:

```
parts is a real folder/directory
anotherpart is a real folder/directory and has all the php files
there are no other files in <root> other then index.php
there are no files in the parts folder/directory
```

Folder/Directory structure:

```
<root>/index.php
<root>/parts/anotherpart/this.php
```

What .htacces I have running:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.happylocation.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://happylocation.it/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/parts/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/parts/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /parts/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The problem is that when browsing to happylocation.it/anotherpart/this it responds with *was not found on this server*. What I hope to achieve is to  have urls like

> happylocation.it/anotherpart/this/friendlypageID

Comment: What is your non-dynamic url? I'm still not clear but if you want it to have multiple dirs in the url you can use http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php to generate your htaccess.

Comment: My non dynamic url is https://happylocation.it/anotherpart/this.php. wich iam trying to change into https://happylocation.it/anotherpart/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/parts/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /parts/$1 [L,QSA]
```

like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /parts/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked, how come that RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/parts/$1 -f messes the .php hide up?

Comment: Because it was never matching. You were saying to only process that rule if `document_root/parts/anotherpart/this` is a real file. Well it's not. So it will never match and the rule will not be executed. You only need to check if the URL is not a real file or not a real directory. Which the first 2 conditions do.